# Variance calculations: sum of powers of matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, variance

I'm facing the following problem:

let $V = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} P^{t}$

where P is a $n \times n$ matrix.

I want to calculate $Var(V)$, variance is calculated coefficient-wise.
I know the variance of each coefficient of $P$ and I also know that this coefficient are correlated with each other.

I've developed a method to approximate this value but it is time expensive.
I would like to know if there is a way to obtain a nice closed formula.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean $P$ is a random matrix / matrix of random variables and you calculate the variance for each random variable (i.e. entry-wise)? Even if you mean these random variables are correlated, I do not see how it affect you calculate individual variance. And have you tried to evaluate $V = (I - P)^{-1}$?

Comment: @BGM I mean a matrix of random variables where each entry is correlated with all the others. Yes I tried to understand what happens to $Var[(I-P)^{-1}]$ in terms of the variance of each entry of P but the inverse of the matrix confuses me.